# Infinite direct sum of projective modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, homological-algebra, projective-module

Let $A$ be a noncommutative algebra over a field $k$, and $M$ a left $A$-module such that 
$$
M = \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i
$$
where $I$ is a countable set, and the decomposition is a decomposition of left $A$-modules. If each $M_i$ is projective as a left $A$-module, can we conclude that $M$ is projective as a left $A$-module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is true.

**Hint for showing that:** Use the universal property of the direct sum in form of the bijection between the respective Hom-sets (or just in terms of the diagram if you prefer that).